# Different ways to use .on() with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am a bit confused about using .on()  Can someone tell me the difference between:

```
$('#detailData').on('click', '.select-topic', function() {
```

and

```
$('#detailData .select-topic').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html). This pretty much covers it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one *delegates* a click event handler to the `#detailData` element. When a click event (that could come from any of its descendants) reaches that element, jQuery checks to see if the event target matches the selector, `.select-topic`. If it does, then the event handler is executed.

This is useful if `.select-topic` elements are added to the DOM dynamically - you can't bind event handlers directly to elements that don't exist yet.

It's possible because most DOM events *bubble* up the tree from the element on which they originate, up through all ancestor elements.

The 2nd example binds a click event handler to all `.select-topic` elements that exist in the DOM at the time the code is executed.

Here's a [simple demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/z2YVP/). For the following markup:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li class="item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item">Item 2</li>
</ul>​
```

Run the following code:

```
$("#myList .item").on("click", function () {
    $(this).text("Clicked!"); 
});

/*$("#myList").on("click", ".item", function () {
    $(this).text("Clicked!"); 
});*/

$("#myList").append("<li class='item'>Item 3</li>");
```

Attempt to click on "Item 3", and nothing will happen. Comment out the first `.on()` call, and uncomment the second. Run it again, and notice how the event handler now runs when you click on "Item 3".

Answer (score 1):

The **first** is for dynamically created elements (`.select-topic`) 
the **second** one will not delegate the click enent listener to newly created elements.

The first one is like the now deprecated `.live()` method.

Comment: The first one is like the non-deprecated "delegate" method would be the correct answer.

Comment: @Christoph in other words, yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#detailData')
.on('click', '.select-topic', function () {
```

binds the click event handler with `#detailData`.

```
$('#detailData .select-topic')
.on('click', function () {
```

binds the click event handler with `#detailData .select-topic`

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) can explain it to you:

> **`.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )`**
>
> **selector** A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is `null` or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

In other words, in both cases the event is attached to the element with ID `detailData`, but in the first case it is delegated to all elements in it matching `'.select-topic'` selector. This will work, even if `'.select-topic'` is not matched at the time it is defined (because you do not attach events to that element, only parent elements).

More about event delegation: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate